# "If you do not mind" or "If you agree": what is the best choice?

Tags: british-english, politeness, email

I am writing an email to my team to ask if I can use their time slot to discuss one of my open questions.

> It looks like this question can be useful for all of us. I think it makes sense to discuss it on Monday.
> Please let me know *if you do not mind* if I take your time.

I am unsure how I can politely ask my team. Should I use *if you do not mind* or *if you agree*?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I just gave your post a quick just to underline that it wasn't a proofreading question (those are off-topic here).

Comment: Anna, we use: If you don't mind, the contraction unless the document is super formal.

Comment: Hi Anna.  I would change "can" to "could" or "might".  Your last sentence isn't right - it's not grammatical.  Maybe you could try "Please let me know if this is convenient for you".

Answer (score 4):

"If you do not mind" is somewhat negative, as if you think you are making an imposition or perhaps even an unreasonable request.

"If you agree" is more positive and suggests you are hopeful that your colleagues will turn up.

One other suggestion might be to replace "if I take your time" with something like "to give some of your time so we can share ideas."

A positively worded request is more likely to elicit a positive response! Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

> Please let me know if you do not mind/if you agree if I take your time.

I'm surprised that nobody has remarked that both of these are not idiomatic and won't be found in any "Business English" text book.

In the context "if you do not mind" sounds aggressive, and "if you agree" leaves open "if you don't agree".

And "if I take your time" is close to incomprehensible.

> It looks like this question <s>can</s> *might* be useful <s>for</s> *to* all of us. I think it makes sense to discuss it on Monday. Please let me know **if this is convenient [for you]**.

(You will obviously include a specific time on Monday...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is going to be hierarchy- and habit-dependent.

If you're the boss…

> Please let me know if you can't free up a slot between 3 & 4pm for us to all get together.

If they're all above you, or your equal…

> Please let me know if you could spare an hour/a few minutes Monday afternoon, say 3pm, for us to all get together.

Adding the 'get together' bit emphasises you don't want to have to speak to all the team individually.
Your current approach leaves too many ways to avoid it.
If you have scheduled meetings anyway, approach the chair to see if it can be added to the agenda & save having to try schedule everyone individually.